# How can I round an array of arrays? I tried already numpy.round

Tags: python, arrays, rounding

```
[[391.88096195], [386.44174122], [378.13177006], [368.87926224]]
```

My output is the above array of arrays, and I want to round it like:

```
[[391.88], [386.44], [378.13], [368.87]]
```

Comment: You said you tried `numpy.round` but you didn't specify how you tried it, or how the results differed from your expectations.

Comment: I tried it like this: np.round(df2)
It gave me the same ouput:  [[391.88096195], [386.44174122], [378.13177006], [368.87926224]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) syntax:

```
>>> arr = [[391.88096195], [386.44174122], [378.13177006], [368.87926224]]
>>> arr = [[round(xx,2) for xx in aa] for aa in arr]
[[391.88], [386.44], [378.13], [368.87]]
```